# Load a tabbarcontroller when back button is clicked in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uitabbarcontroller

When i click on back button then Im loading a particular view.But to that particular view I have to add a tabbarController.How can i do it..?When i try to add it doesnot get added..Couldnot understand y ?

```
 -(IBAction)switchtofirst {
AppViewController *first=[[AppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppViewController" bundle:nil];  
        Login *second=[[Login alloc]initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
        second.title=@"Login";
        NSArray *viewArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: first,second,nil];
        tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
        [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewArray animated:NO];
        AppViewController *gp=[AppViewController alloc];
         [gp.view addSubview:tabBarController.view]; 
      [self presentModalViewController:gp animated:NO];
        [gp release];
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
-(IBAction)switchtofirst {

    AppViewController *first = [[AppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppViewController" bundle:nil];
    Login *second=[[Login alloc]initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
    second.title=@"Login";

    NSArray *viewArray= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:first, second, nil];

    tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewArray animated:NO];

    [self presentViewController:tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Im getting error :"Program received SIGABRT" at this line:[self presentViewController:tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];Can u please tell me how to rectify it ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @bbodayle. solved my headache. + 1 for a good answer.